# Form submission canceled because the form is not connected error while using form with redux store. how to fix this error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-redux, redux-form

I'am trying to trigger an automatic click with another on a page, however, the states are updating in the redux store for the second click, there is a search button as existing website functionality. I have setup another search form input on the same search below. Also used the states which change in redux store. it gives me the error as "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected.". Is there a way to fix this?

I have tried few options, using keypress methods from jquery and auto detecting clicks using jquery:

```
let search = $selector.find('.t130-searchInput').val().trim()
if (search) {
  $input.val(search)
  store.dispatch({
      type: "SET_FORM_FIELD",
      field: "searchTerm",
      formName: "search",
      value: search,
      key: null,
      isDirty: true
  });
 $button.click()
}
```